# CAPI2 The Proxy Auto-configuration URL was not found

Tags: asp.net, httpclient

I have a asp.net mvc application. running on windows server 2008 R2  and framework 4.5.
On one controller. I use httpclient post xml  to remote soap server via https channel. but very slow. it take 6 seconds to finish the request. I enable CAPI2  log. found error:

```
> System 
>
>  - Provider 
>
>   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2 
>   [ Guid]  {5bbca4a8-b209-48dc-a8c7-b23d3e5216fb} 
> 
>   EventID 53 
> 
>   Version 0 
> 
>   Level 2 
> 
>  Task 53 
> 
>   Opcode 2 
> 
>   Keywords 0x4000000000000036 
> 
>  - TimeCreated 
>
>   [ SystemTime]  2013-03-06T00:09:12.342400000Z 
> 
>   EventRecordID 226 
> 
>   Correlation 
> 
>  - Execution 
>
>   [ ProcessID]  4716 
>   [ ThreadID]  3620 
> 
>   Channel Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational 
> 
>   Computer WIN-PFVACQLB4A9 
> 
>  - Security 
>
>   [ UserID]  S-1-5-82-100694679-852442941-408577778-1461352480-452402374 
> 
>
>- UserData 
>
>  - CryptRetrieveObjectByUrlWire 
>
>  - URL http://gtssldv-aia.geotrust.com/gtssldv.crt 
>
>   [ scheme]  http 
> 
>  - Object 
>
>   [ type]  CONTEXT_OID_CERTIFICATE 
>   [ constant]  1 
> 
>   Timeout PT15S 
> 
>  - Flags 
>
>   [ value]  286005 
>   [ CRYPT_RETRIEVE_MULTIPLE_OBJECTS]  true 
>   [ CRYPT_WIRE_ONLY_RETRIEVAL]  true 
>   [ CRYPT_LDAP_SCOPE_BASE_ONLY_RETRIEVAL]  true 
>   [ CRYPT_OFFLINE_CHECK_RETRIEVAL]  true 
>   [ CRYPT_AIA_RETRIEVAL]  true 
>   [ CRYPT_PROXY_CACHE_RETRIEVAL]  true 
> 
>  - AuxInfo 
>
>   [ maxUrlRetrievalByteCount]  100000 
>   [ fProxyCacheRetrieval]  true 
> 
>  - AdditionalInfo 
>
>  - NetworkConnectivityStatus 
>
>   [ value]  1 
>   [ _SENSAPI_NETWORK_ALIVE_LAN]  true 
> 
>  - Action 
>
>   [ name]  Call_WinHttpGetProxyForUrl 
>  - Error The Proxy Auto-configuration URL was not found. 
>
>   [ value]  2F94 
> 
> 
>  - Action 
>
>   [ name]  NoProxy 
> 
>  - Action 
>
>   [ name]  Call_WinHttpGetProxyForUrl 
>  + Error The Proxy Auto-configuration URL was not found. 
>
>   [ value]  2F94 
> 
> 
>  - Action 
>
>   [ name]  NoProxy 
> 
>  - HTTPRequestHeadersInfo 
>
>   Header GET /gtssldv.crt HTTP/1.1 
> 
>   Header Accept: */* 
> 
>   Header User-Agent: Microsoft-CryptoAPI/6.1 
> 
>   Header Connection: Keep-Alive 
> 
> 
>  - HTTPResponseHeadersInfo 
>
>   Header HTTP/1.0 200 OK 
> 
>   Header Connection: Keep-Alive 
> 
>   Header Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2013 23:43:39 GMT 
> 
>   Header Via: NS-248 
> 
>   Header Via: 1.0 hostname:80 (squid/2.6.STABLE21) 
> 
>  Header Content-Length: 1022 
> 
>   Header Content-Type: text/plain 
> 
>   Header Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Jul 2010 18:25:03 GMT 
> 
>   Header Accept-Ranges: bytes 
> 
>   Header Age: 540 
> 
>   Header ETag: "25f7fb-3fe-48be9eb969dc0" 
> 
>   Header Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) 
> 
>   Header X-Pad: avoid browser bug 
> 
>   Header X-Cache: MISS from hostname 
> 
>   Header X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from hostname:80 
> 
> 
>  - Action 
>
>   [ name]  WriteToCache 
>  - Error The system cannot find the file specified. 
>
>   [ value]  80070002 
> 
> 
> 
>  - CacheInfo 
>
>   [ lastSyncTime]  2013-03-06T00:09:12.342Z 
>  - URLCacheResponseInfo 
>
>  [ responseType]  CRYPTNET_URL_CACHE_RESPONSE_HTTP 
>   [ lastModifiedTime]  2010-07-21T18:25:03Z 
>   [ eTag]  "25f7fb-3fe-48be9eb969dc0" 
>   [ proxyId]  DEAE4085 
> 
> 
>  - RetrievedObjects 
>
>  - Certificate 
>
>   [ fileRef]  BAE30B15DBB1544CF194D076B75B7BB9E3D6B760.cer 
>   [ subjectName]  GeoTrust DV SSL CA 
> 
> 
>  - EventAuxInfo 
>
>   [ ProcessName]  w3wp.exe 
> 
>  - CorrelationAuxInfo 
>
>   [ TaskId]  {2B4FC750-01D1-4D7E-BEEF-A3F9DD09B0E8} 
>   [ SeqNumber]  4 
> 
>  - Result 
>
>   [ value]  0
```

I also unchecked Internet Exploer->Internet Opitions->Connections->LAN Settings-> Automatically detect settings. nothing change.

Looking for help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's too late but the way I solved the same exact problem was to find the user ID, in your case:

```
[ UserID]  S-1-5-82-100694679-852442941-408577778-1461352480-452402374
```

inside the registry, in the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList .
```

It will tell you which user is invoking the Crypto API 2 (CAPI2), in my case was "Classic .NET Application Pool" or similar.

I fixed it by impersonating (running the process as another user with enough rights), then I did not have anymore this write errors and therefore not the red error messages in the event log.

For this, I have created an user with administrator rights in the local computer (I know it is not the most secure option, but I had to try, and it worked). In the end, seemed that the problem was the proxy but was that particular error:.

```
>   [ name]  WriteToCache 
>  - Error The system cannot find the file specified. 
>
>   [ value]  80070002 
>
```

It had no write rights somewhere, but the Administrator does :P

Also another thing I did (as the crypto API were requesting always the CRL), in the Local Group Policy Editor, following the path:

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Public Keys > Certificate Path Validation Settings > "Revocation" tab. Enable "Define these policy settings" and also enable "Allow CRL and OCSP responses to be valid longer than their lifetime".

Then I extended the validity of this CRL into one year (8760 hours), I know it is also too long, but it depends on your needs or security concerns, in my case is safe enough.

I hope it helps you out

Answer (score 0):

My answer is taken from here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/82c52c69-1a53-4f48-8c7e-37bc7364dca3/

Setup an IIS server such that it would respond with javascript inside http://wpad.mylab.local/wpad.dat - don't forget to add the MIME type for wpad.dat (application/x-javascript is fine).  If you don't have the need for a proxy, then the  javascript in your wpad.dat file should look like the following:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

After that, you should no longer have event 53 in the CAPI2 logs when using certutil.